# How can I programmatically insert a MAC address into /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: string, bash, ubuntu, text, insert

I am trying to write a script that uses a user-created MAC address when using the `wlan0` interface.

To test, I made a file called `testFile.txt`, which is a copy of `/etc/network/interfaces`. If there are interfaces after `wlan0`, I cannot use `echo "$var" >> testFile.txt` because that simply adds the text to the end.

I am able to find the end of the `wlan0` interface text, but I am not sure how to insert there.  Below is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter MAC Address"
read var
log=$(cat testFile.txt | grep -o "wlan0.*" | grep -o dhcp)
echo $log
```

`echo $log` prints `dhcp`.

I tried adding `| echo "hwaddress ether $var" >> testFile.txt` to `$log` but that still appends to the end of the file.
How do I insert directly after `$log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Problem

1. Useless use of *cat*. Don't do that.
2. You're not using the right tool for the job. Use GNU sed to make life easier on yourself.

#### The Solution

```
# Insert hwaddress line into /etc/network/interfaces.
read -p "Enter MAC Address: "
sudo sed -i.bak "/iface wlan0/a\    hwaddress $REPLY" /etc/network/interfaces

# Replace existing hwaddress line in /etc/network/interfaces.
read -p "Enter MAC Address: "
sudo sed -ri.bak "s/(hwaddress).*/\1 $REPLY/"
```

Comment: @Peter: It's Useless. `grep` accepts filenames as arguments. (One of the reasons it's useless is you're spawning an extra process needlessly.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `sed` to insert the MAC address.  If you want to insert it at the end of the line with wlan0, that would be

```
sed "s/\(wlan0.*\)/\1 $var/" testFile.txt > testFile.txt.tmp
```

If that works, then

```
mv testFile.txt.tmp testFile.txt
```

Comment: Useless use of cat.  Sed takes files as arguments directly.

Comment: This seems to work, but with a few issues.  First, I can't figure out how to get newline to work.  It just writes the \n to the document and everything else next to dhcp instead of the line below.  Second, this doesn't seem to make the edit to the file.

Answer (score -1):

you need a different tool, SED for example

```
$ seq 5 | sed '/3/ s/.*/something else/'
1
2
something else
4
5
```

for example you can Substitute the line with '3' by 'something else' - and there is no limits

Comment: While recommending sed is useful, your answer doesn't address the OP's question of how to modify the MAC address.

Comment: Well, the basic syntax of sed is easy to learn and use for this question. My intention was only show the tool, if it is not acceptable, sorry.